# software-properties-gtk doesn't work

Tags: bash, software-center, python3

Ubuntu 16.04

software-properties-gtk doesn't work. I saw some errors with /usr/bin/python folder. I hoped, I will repaire it myself.

I removed folder python3 in /usr/bin/ (yes, I know that was stupid)

When I run`software-properties-gtk` the OUTPUT is:

`bash: /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

How fix this mistake?

**UPDATE:**

When I type `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal`, OUTUPT is:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 28,1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 python-minimal amd64 2.7.12-1~16.04 [28,1 kB]
Fetched 28,1 kB in 0s (77,8 kB/s)

(Reading database ... 248904 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-minimal_2.7.12-1~16.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-minimal (2.7.12-1~16.04) over (2.7.12-1~16.04) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up python3-minimal (3.5.1-3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: py3compile: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.12-1~16.04) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal` ?

Comment: OUTPUT:  `E: Internal Error, No file name for python3-minimal:amd64`

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal`.

Comment: I updated question

Comment: Try to install packages manually with `sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/python-minimal_2.7.12-1~16.04_amd64.deb` and `sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-minimal_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb`.

Comment: First commend: OK. Next one: INPUT:  `sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-minimal_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb` OUTPUT: `Setting up python3-minimal (3.5.1-3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: py3compile: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-minimal`

Comment: If You don't like comment form. I will Update question

Comment: I started to form the answer. We will clean comments on success. Try p.3 with `dpkg -x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'll summarize all actions which were taken to fix the problem:

1. Install packages as usual:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal
   ```
2. Install packages on low-level:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/python-minimal_2.7.12-1~16.04_amd64.deb 
   sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-minimal_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Extract packages directly to file-system and then continue as usual:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -x /var/cache/apt/archives/python-minimal_2.7.12-1~16.04_amd64.deb /
   sudo dpkg -x /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-minimal_3.5.1-3_amd64.deb /
   sudo apt-get install -f
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```